# Network faster than ISP offers

Tags: wireless-networking, isp

We're switching from ISP soon but I still wanted to know something about our old one.

Our ISP offers 2.4 GHz networks only and we bought a new router this year, which in turn supports 5 GHz.

(Our new ISP will support 5 GHz anyway so no issue with that ISP (not that we got one with our current one, tbh, the new one is cheaper))

We bought a new router because our network was too slow and everyone had issues with connecting etc on the official one from the ISP.

We have fiber (not from Google, because the Netherlands doesn't have Google fiber) and we're switching to cable. Also my current ISP gives us 2.4 GHz.

My phone is connected to the 5 GHz network which is on by default on the new router. This gives my phone a huge boost of speed.

The 2.4 GHz network gives me 30 Mbit/s download and my 5 GHz one 70/71 Mbit/s. I tested it on ookla.net it connects well.

The connection is normally on 2.4 GHz 72 Mbit/s and my 5 GHz one 433 Mbit/s So let's get to the questions.

Can our ISP let us pay an higher bill for using more bandwith than they offer?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please consider rewording it. It's possible you are confused about 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. These aren't speeds.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I putted it quick up. I will update the question

Comment: The last paragraph still makes no sense.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Better now?

Comment: No. Hopefully someone else can come along and edit the question so that it makes sense, I literally can't figure out what you are asking.

Comment: If I can get a higher bill because I use a faster network type?

Comment: I think the question is:  Can I pay my ISP more for higher bandwidth?

Comment: @N.Greene No it's if my ISP can charge more, I know what I mean

Comment: @CedianO So you are saying, If somehow I use more bandwidth than my ISP allows, will they charge me more?

Comment: @N.Greene Yes that's it.

Comment: @N.Greene I updated the question

Comment: @CedianO How would you use more bandwidth than they allow?  ISP is giving your "pipe" of upload/download speed.  ISP would determine what your max up/down speed is before the signal gets to your house.

Comment: @N.Greene Yeah, but weirdly enough according to ookla it's around twice as fast

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qj5yKOK.png for my network speed

Comment: What speeds does the ISP claim they offer?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz around 100 Mbit/s on 2 4 GHz.

Comment: And you're showing less than that. So your question makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well my phone's connection says it's 72 on 2.4 and 433 on 5 and that's not up/down the up/down is always lower than they offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ISP neither knows nor cares how fast the link is between your own devices. It's very common to have a local network that's much faster than your network connection. In many cases, it's essential if you're doing local backup or streaming.

I suppose it's possible that you have some very unusual arrangement with your ISP that demands you have a slow local network. But I've never heard of such a thing.